# How do I subclass Raphael.st

Tags: javascript, raphael, subclassing

I have a number of logical objects in my charting application, each of which consist of a number of Raphael objects. For example, a data point might consist of a circle and a caption.

I would like to be able to process all those objects as one, and also be able to determine which logical object any given Raphael element belongs to (e.g. to process mouse clicks on an element on the context of the logical element to which it belongs).

I hope to be able to make a subclass of Raphael.st (i.e. a Raphael set), and to override the push method to set element.data("object") to the containing logical object.

In other places in the code, I use the following subclass method (which I found on Stack Overflow):

```
/**
 * Utility function to help subclassing
 * @param base
 * @param sub
 */
function subclass(base, sub) {
    // Avoid instantiating the base class just to setup inheritance
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create
    // for a polyfill
    sub.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
    // Remember the constructor property was set wrong, let's fix it
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
    // In ECMAScript5+ (all modern browsers), you can make the constructor property
    // non-enumerable if you define it like this instead
    Object.defineProperty(sub.prototype, 'constructor', {
        enumerable: false,
        value: sub
    });
}
```

However, this method is throwing an exception because base.prototype is null when base = Raphael.st.

I apologise for my ignorance of how subclassing really works in javascript - I realise blindly copying code from elsewhere is not ideal, but I haven't found an explanation I understand yet!

Can anyone tell me how to subclass Raphael.st, and/or point me in the direction of an explanation that will enable me to work out how for myself?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to subclass Raphael.set, because Raphael isn't expecting it. For example, lots of code in Raphael which needs to know whether it is dealing with a set or not uses code like:

```
if (element.constructor == R.st.constructor)
```

which means a proper subclass would fail the test.

If you still want to proceed (and don't have any clashing property or function names, like I did when I tried it!), I did find the answer.

The subclass function needs to be modified, because Raphael does not follow the usual convention - Raphael.st is not a class, it is the prototype for the class. The subclass method should therefore be modified as follows:

```
function subclass(base, sub) {
// Avoid instantiating the base class just to setup inheritance
// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create
// for a polyfill
sub.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype ? base.prototype : base);
// Remember the constructor property was set wrong, let's fix it
sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
// In ECMAScript5+ (all modern browsers), you can make the constructor property
// non-enumerable if you define it like this instead
Object.defineProperty(sub.prototype, 'constructor', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: sub
});
}
```

Here is the subclass constructor:

```
/**
 * @param paper Raphael Paper
 */
var MySet = function(paper) {
Raphael.st.constructor.call(this);
// Without this, Raphael does not recognise MySet objects as sets
// because it tests constructor value using == instead of instanceof
this.constructor = Raphael.st.constructor;
// Cheat!! Copied this code from Raphael Paper.set()
this.paper = paper;
};

subclass(Raphael.st, MySet);
```

Hope this helps someone else!